# How can I make a grid view row editable?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When I click the left mouse button on a corresponding row in my grid view control I want that row to turn editable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find gridview editing and more : [ASP.NET Quickstart Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)

Also this is another example : [MSDN GridView RowEditing Event Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx)

Comment: That first link doesn't help at all anymore.